# Sql server query with common table expression

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `Dim_Zone` with the following schema:

```
(Zone_ID int, Zone_RecursID int, Zone_Label varchar(50), zone level int, zone_active bit)
```

`ZoneRecurs_ID` is the parent ID of `Zone_ID`

```
Zone level 0 stands for World
Zone level 1 stands for Continent_ID
Zone level 2 stands for Country_ID
Zone level 3 stands for Superregion_ID
Zone level 4 stands for region_ID
Zone level 5 stands for departement_ID
```

I need a query that give me the following columns:

```
departement_ID, region_ID,  Superregion_ID, Country_ID  ,continent_id,  departement_label,  region_label,   Superregion_label,  Country_label,  continent_label ,dimItem_level
```

so I need a final result like:

```
departement_ID  region_ID   Superregion_ID  Country_ID  continent_id    departement_label   region_label    Superregion_label           Country_label       continent_label     dimItem_level
NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL        404             NULL                NULL            NULL                        NULL                Europe              1
NULL            NULL        NULL            158         406             NULL                NULL            NULL                        Itali               Europe              2
NULL            NULL        12              1           406             NULL                NULL            Centre                      France              Europe              3
NULL            139         137             1           406             NULL                Mayotte         Collectivités d'Outre Mer   France              Europe              4
20              18          12              1           406             Oise                Picardie        Bassin Parisien             France              Europe              5
```

I tried the following code:

```sql
WITH departements
     AS (SELECT DZ.zone_id,
                zone_recursid,
                zone_label,
                zone_level,
                zone_active
         FROM   dim_zone DZ
         WHERE  zone_level = 5
                AND zone_active = 1),
     regions
     AS (SELECT DZ.zone_id,
                zone_recursid,
                zone_label,
                zone_level,
                zone_active
         FROM   dim_zone DZ
         WHERE  zone_level = 4
                AND zone_active = 1),
     superregions
     AS (SELECT DZ.zone_id,
                zone_recursid,
                zone_label,
                zone_level,
                zone_active
         FROM   dim_zone DZ
         WHERE  zone_level = 3
                AND zone_active = 1),
     country
     AS (SELECT DZ.zone_id,
                zone_recursid,
                zone_label,
                zone_level,
                zone_active
         FROM   dim_zone DZ
         WHERE  zone_level = 2
                AND zone_active = 1),
     continents
     AS (SELECT DZ.zone_id,
                zone_recursid,
                zone_label,
                zone_level,
                zone_active
         FROM   dim_zone DZ
         WHERE  zone_level = 1
                AND zone_active = 1) SELECT NULL       AS departement_ID,
       NULL       AS region_ID,
       NULL       AS SuperRegion_ID,
       NULL       AS Country_ID,
       zone_id    AS continent_id,
       NULL       AS departement_label,
       NULL       AS region_label,
       NULL       AS SuperRegion_label,
       NULL       AS Country_label,
       zone_label AS continent_label,
       1          AS dimItem_level
FROM   continents
UNION
SELECT D.zone_id     AS departement_ID,
       R.zone_id     AS region_ID,
       SR.zone_id    AS SuperRegion_ID,
       P.zone_id     AS Country_ID,
       C.zone_id     AS continent_id,
       D.zone_label  AS departement_label,
       R.zone_label  AS region_label,
       SR.zone_label AS SuperRegion_label,
       P.zone_label  AS Country_label,
       C.zone_label  AS continent_label,
       CASE
         WHEN D.zone_id IS NOT NULL THEN 5
         WHEN R.zone_id IS NOT NULL THEN 4
         WHEN SR.zone_id IS NOT NULL THEN 3
         WHEN P.zone_id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
         WHEN C.zone_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END           AS dimitem_level
FROM   continents C
       LEFT JOIN country P
              ON C.zone_id = P.zone_recursid
       LEFT JOIN superregions SR
              ON P.zone_id = SR.zone_recursid
       LEFT JOIN regions R
              ON SR.zone_id = R.zone_recursid
       LEFT JOIN departements D
              ON R.zone_id = D.zone_recursid
```

Does anyone have an idea why or suggest any other way to do it?

Comment: If the number of levels is fixed (6) then use 6 union all queries, each query involves 0, 1, 2, ... inner joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the `FROM` clause. You are starting with the continents and doing `LEFT JOIN` against lower levels. This will only display 1 level and not all 6 as your need.

You want to see 6 different result sets, so you need 6 `SELECT` with 5 `UNION ALL`, once for each level you have (`departments`, `regions`, `superRegions`, `countries`, `continents` and `world`).

I strongly suggest creating different views for each CTE, it will make writing a lot more readable.

I'll write the most complex 2 as example, you can add the rest:

```
;With departements as
(
    select DZ.Zone_ID, Zone_RecursID, Zone_label, Zone_level, Zone_Active 
    from Dim_Zone DZ
    where Zone_Level = 5 and zone_active=1
), 
regions as
(
    select DZ.Zone_ID, Zone_RecursID, Zone_label, Zone_level, Zone_Active 
    from Dim_Zone DZ
    where Zone_Level = 4 and zone_active=1
), 
superRegions as
(
    select DZ.Zone_ID, Zone_RecursID, Zone_label, Zone_level, Zone_Active 
    from Dim_Zone DZ
    where Zone_Level = 3 and zone_active=1
), 
Country as(
    select DZ.Zone_ID, Zone_RecursID, Zone_label, Zone_level, Zone_Active 
    from Dim_Zone DZ
    where Zone_Level = 2 and zone_active=1
),
continents as
(
    select DZ.Zone_ID, Zone_RecursID, Zone_label, Zone_level, Zone_Active 
    from Dim_Zone DZ
    where Zone_Level = 1 and zone_active=1
)

-- Departments
Select 
    D.Zone_id as departement_ID,
    R.Zone_ID as region_ID,
    SR.Zone_ID as SuperRegion_ID,
    P.Zone_ID as Country_ID,
    C.Zone_ID as continent_id, 

    D.Zone_label as departement_label,
    R.Zone_label as region_label,
    SR.Zone_label as SuperRegion_label,
    P.Zone_label as Country_label,
    C.Zone_label as continent_label,

    case
        when D.Zone_ID is not null then 5
        when R.Zone_ID is not null then 4
        when SR.Zone_ID is not null then 3
        when P.Zone_ID is not null then 2
        when C.Zone_ID is not null then 1
        else 0
    end as dimitem_level
from
    departements AS D
    INNER JOIN regions AS R ON D.Zone_recursID = R.ZoneID
    INNER JOIN superRegions AS SR ON R.Zone_recursID = SR.ZoneID
    INNER JOIN Country AS P ON SR.Zone_recursID = P.ZoneID
    INNER JOIN continents AS C ON P.Zone_recursID = C.ZoneID

UNION ALL

-- Regions
Select 
    NULL as departement_ID,                     -- Department data is NULL
    R.Zone_ID as region_ID,
    SR.Zone_ID as SuperRegion_ID,
    P.Zone_ID as Country_ID,
    C.Zone_ID as continent_id, 

    NULL as departement_label,                  -- Department data is NULL
    R.Zone_label as region_label,
    SR.Zone_label as SuperRegion_label,
    P.Zone_label as Country_label,
    C.Zone_label as continent_label,

    case                                        -- Department case is omitted
        when R.Zone_ID is not null then 4
        when SR.Zone_ID is not null then 3
        when P.Zone_ID is not null then 2
        when C.Zone_ID is not null then 1
        else 0
    end as dimitem_level
from
    regions AS R
    INNER JOIN superRegions AS SR ON R.Zone_recursID = SR.ZoneID
    INNER JOIN Country AS P ON SR.Zone_recursID = P.ZoneID
    INNER JOIN continents AS C ON P.Zone_recursID = C.ZoneID

-- UNION ALL

-- superRegions
-- Country
-- continents
```